# Putting circular icon buttons on right side of header bar - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

At the moment my mobile app looks similar to the one on the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/TM6Dt/

with the following code:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1 data-inline="true">Demo Page</h1>

      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext">Mail</a>
      <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Settings</a>

  </div>

<div data-role="content" class="content">

    <p>Demo Page</p>



</div>



</div>

</body>
```

What I'd like to do is have both of the circular buttons on the right side of the header bar. I've tried putting them in a `controlgroup` div but for some reason this changes them so they are no longer circular - I get square buttons with the icons in the middle. What's worse is they are not even aligned properly! You can see what I mean here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gd8ZB/

and the code:

```
<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1 data-inline="true">Demo Page</h1>
       <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext">Mail</a>
          <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Settings</a>
       </div>

  </div>

<div data-role="content" class="content">

    <p>Demo Page</p>



</div>



</div>

</body>
```

How do I get around this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done that as follows:

```
<div class="ui-btn-right">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="mail" data-iconpos="notext">Mail</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Settings</a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/TM6Dt/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TM6Dt/1/

one way to do it is to change position of the first button in first example and move it to the right with following css

```
 style="right: 40px; left: initial;"
```